# jQuery Horizontal Scrolling?

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to show animation on the below to show the horizantal scroll is there. Which means i the scroll move left few second and right few second after page load completed

Answer (score 1):

You can try this by using jquery plugin.

Here I have attached the [Github link.](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin)

Here is the [Plugin webpage.](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

You can also find the examples for the horizontal scrolling from this [link](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html).

Hope this may helps you.